# distriqt compass isSupported false

Tags: compass, distriqt

I bought the Compass ANE from distriqt and in my mobile ( BLU life 8 XL, android 4.4 ) get Compass.isSupported false.

Somebody try this ANE before? why I get unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons `isSupported` may return false:

- If the ANE is incorrectly added to your project and you are using the default library. You can rule this out by tracing `Compass.service.version` and ensuring it contains `Android`.
- Secondly the ANE checks if the device has an accelerometer and a magnetometer, which are used to determine the orientation. If the device doesn't have either of these sensors then it will return false.